# Create a random generation using two ranges of numbers and remove duplicates.(C++)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a random generation of numbers using two ranges of numbers. For example :

```
value = rand() % 13 + 1;
suit = rand() % 4 + 1;
cout<<cardd<<color<<endl;
```

This is a piece of the program I'm using, I want to create from four colors of cars, 13 models. Is there any way to remove duplicates?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "duplicates"?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049748/how-to-make-random-numbers-unique or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41560927/inserting-unique-random-numbers-into-a-vector

Comment: With those numbers you could fill a vector with all possible combinations and remove them as needed.

Comment: Instead of trying to remove duplicates, why don't you just [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) a bunch of cards and pick the first few?

Answer (score 0):

You may store the values in a `std::set`, or simply erase duplicates from a vector:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
vec.erase(std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()), vec.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your actual problem. But I can do something for eliminating duplicates in random numbers.

First, the next two lines are problematic:

```
value = rand() % 13 + 1;
suit = rand() % 4 + 1;
```

because `rand() % M` can't generator the complete range of random numbers in `[0,M-1]`. The real reason is that `rand()` is generates a random number in `[0,INT_MAX]`, but `INT_MAX` sometimes can't divide `M` exactly.

If you don't want to use `<random>` like above. You can modify it a little.

```
  value =((double)rand())/INT_MAX * 13 ;
  suit = ((double)rand())/INT_MAX*4;
```

Finally I suggest `std::default_random_engine` and `uniform_int_distribution`, like the following:

```
static std::default_random_engine e(time(0));
uniform_int_distribution u(1,13);

unordered_set<int> numbers;
int number;
do
{
   number=u(e);
}while(numbers.find(number)!=numbers.end());
numbers.insert(number);
```

I just  mean you can use `unordered_set<int>` to record the generated numbers, and to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a pair, then you can compare each new pair to a vector of pairs:

First create the vector:

```
vector<pair<int,int>> deck;
```

Then inside your loop, create cards:

```
pair <int,int> card;
card.first = ((double)rand())/INT_MAX * 13;
card.second = ((double)rand())/INT_MAX*4;
```

Then use binary_search to add only non-duplicates to the deck:

```
if(!binary_search(deck.begin(), deck.end(), card)){
  deck.push_back(card);
}
```

Here is a working prototype that probably suits your needs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits.h>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    std::vector <std::pair<int,int>> deck;
    for(int n = 0;n < 52;n++){
        std::pair <int,int> card;
        card.first = ((double)rand())/INT_MAX * 13;
        card.second = ((double)rand())/INT_MAX*4;
        if(!binary_search(deck.begin(), deck.end(), card)){
            deck.push_back(card);
            std::sort(deck.begin(), deck.end());
            std::cout << "\n" << card.first << " " << card.second;
        }else{
            std::cout << "\ndiscarding duplicate: " << card.first << " " << card.second;
            n--;
        }
    }
}
```

But Fei Xang's idea to just create a deck and shuffle it makes more sense.